# How do I code the red email signin button for Firebase authentication?

Tags: email, button, firebase-authentication

My Firebase app uses Google signin as well as non-Gmail signin. I've seen the little red "Sign in with email" button [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui), but I couldn't find a layout that shows how to code it. My login activity looks like the following:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Views
    findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.emailSignInButton).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

}
```

and here's activity_login:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/signInButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailSignInButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signInButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email_signin"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to replace the Button tag with something that will render the same button one gets using AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(). I don't want to use the approach given on the page I referenced above as that not only violates best principles (declare the UI in XML rather than coding it inline) but also would necessitate major changes to code that's already working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but that screenshot is from FirebaseUI. So you'll need to implement that library (as explained on the page you linked), and then [enable email sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui#set_up_sign-in_methods). If you're having trouble making that work, post the exact steps/code that you tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for responding, Frank. I already have FirebaseUI installed, but I don't know how to display the red button, since I don't know what they coded from the picture on that page. For example, to display the Google signin button, I coded com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton in my layout. I had hoped that the red email signin button would be in com.google.android.gms.common, but it wasn't.

Comment: Email sign-in used to be enabled by default, but it seems you now have to explicitly add it. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#adding-providers I you can't get that to work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete code that can be used to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: But using AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build() is inconsistent with best principles, isn't it? The UI should be built from XML, not inline code.

Comment: The UI is built in XML, but configured from code. I guess FirebaseUI has its own best principles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen's suggestion, I found the button I needed:

```
        <com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.SupportVectorDrawablesButton
        android:id="@+id/email_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button.AccountChooser.EmailButton"
        android:text="@string/fui_sign_in_with_email"
        tools:ignore="UnusedIds" /> <!-- Used in tests -->
```